# Update Entities when database changes Entity Framework Code-First Migration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework Code-First approach which use Migration to generate Database from my Code.However, because my database is shared with many projects, so if any project makes change to the Entities(For instance: add or delete a column to an entity) How can I update the Entity from the database? I've read some blogs but It only mentions about Code-first from an existing database so it has .edmx file to update it easily.
I've tried to run **Add-Migration** and **Update-Database** command, but It didn't work.

Comment: i think you should use database first approach

Comment: Actually, I have to apply Reposistory pattern and Unit of Work so code-first is easy to implement. But the problem here is the database has to be shared with others project, so is there anyway to automatically re-new the entities when database makes change instead of write the code to my project

Comment: Use "Code First" from database with EF Tools or the EF Reverse POCO Template

Comment: what are the errors you are encountering with the commands ,, is it possible that it is the `name already in use by an existing object`